# React Native 0.56/0.57 Geolocation watchPosition update rate

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I’m building an app with `react-native init` and maps. I wanted to show real-time user location by using `watchPosition` but the update rate is very slow like 5-8 second per location update. I’d brought this up in the `react-native` [issue page](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21061) a week ago but got no response yet. I’ve tried using both google maps and native iOS maps, as well as building the app as production version but non of them helped solve the issue. For more detailed set up and gif showing the problem, please go the the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21061) that I opened.

Please let me know if this happens to you or it’s just me. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway react-native in build geolocation service has few bugs on their own which doesn't allow some devices to get their location, There is an another plugin which works for me, [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service), it works fine with any device and also if user didn't provide certain permission plugin will auto redirect user to permission setting to get user permission. This improved plugin will help you to over come your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me. My update rate still jumps to 5-8 seconds after using that plugin. Although it may help with the Android situation, they mentioned in their doc that there's nothing changed in the iOS side so I think that's why it doesn't work for me.